# How to add field with its data from one model to another one in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Django already has a User model, which has a username field; I also have a Profile model.
What I want to achieve is to send the username from the User model along with the fields of the Profile model, So that I can access the username from the Profile model itself , as to the frontend I'm returning an object of the Profile model

MODELS

```
User= get_user_model()


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    department= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    degree= models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    year= models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profileimg= models.TextField(default=DEFAULT_IMAGE_DATA)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

SERIALIZER

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields=['id','user', 'id_user', 'department', 'degree', 'year', 'bio','profileimg']


class ChatMsgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reciever_profile= ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    sender_profile= ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ChatMsg
        fields=['id','user', 'sender','sender_profile', 'reciever','reciever_profile', 'msg', 'is_read', 'date']
```

One Solution I though Was to make another fetch request from the frontend and make one more endpoint that returns the username , but idts it would work well when i need both sender and reciever username

Comment: Why does it has both a `user` and `id_user`?

Comment: user is supposed to act as foreign key, while id_user is unique to that model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'id_user',
            'department',
            'degree',
            'year',
            'bio',
            'profileimg',
        ]
```

Comment: Hi, but where does it specify that username has to be picked up from the User model?

Comment: @AbhayChandra: in `slug_field='username'`.

Comment: @AbhayChandra: you did change the (already) defined `ProfileSerializer`?

Answer (score 1):

##### Problem with your solution

You don't need to tweak the framework. Make use of the powerful django framework!

##### Djangonic solution

You can access all `user` attributes from a `Profile` entry directly! To get the user's `last_name` from a `Profile` entry called `some_profile`:

- in Python: `some_profile.user.last_name` ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships))
- in queries: `some_profile__user__last_name` ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships))
- in HTML: `{{ some_profile.user.last_name }}`

##### Recommendation

One recommendation, instead of `ForeignKey`, make use of `OneToOneField` ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField)). It is similar to a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, which makes sense in this case because a `user` can only be linked to a unique `Profile`.

```py
class Expert(models.Model):
    # Use 'OneToOneField' instead of ForeignKey
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # The rest is unchanged
```